# Local offset of clock

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, 7.0-nougat, clock, clock-speed

I'm using the App ClockSync on a Android 7.0 device (Huawei P9 Plus) and on a Android 5.1 device (Huawei MediaPad M2) and I face two problems.

1. I'm synchronizing the time with [ClockSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.org.amip.ClockSync) on my Huawei P9 Plus device. When I then restart the device, the clock has a local offset of around 76 seconds. Why is that? By the way the device is rooted (TWRP). This only happens when I restart the phone.
2. On my Huawei MediaPad M2 device the local offset of the clock (shown by ClockSync) increases over time. After one hour I have an offset of 1 second. How can I decrease this massive offset? Automatic time synchronization is no option because I'm recording sensor data and I don't want to have a sudden jump in the timestamps.

   On the other hand on my Huawei P9 Plus device the offset is not monotonically increasing but just jumps around and is always lower than 1 second. Why is the local offset jumping around? I have disabled automatic time synchronization in ClockSync and also in the system settings.

Comment: As your device is rooted have you tried to simply [re-configure the built in NTP system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381005)? BTW. Android can also use GPS or mobile network for time synchronization. As you have problems with the correct time I assume the device is GPS-offline and Wifi only, richt?

Comment: @Robert Ok I could set the ntp server but how do I know when the time is synchronized? For example I would like to have every min a synchronization.

Comment: @Robert Yes, it is GP-offline and Wifi only because it is used indoors.